# SearchAll method - throw an exception or not?

Tags: c++, exception, queue

I have the following two methods in a class, the first to return a pair of data and associated priority upon searching for an item in the data structure, the second to return a vector of pairs of all instances of the data searched for:

```
/**
* @brief Searches for an item in the PQ and returns the item with corresponding priority
*
* @param item Object to search for in the priority queue
* @return A std::pair containing the object and its corresponding priority
* @throw Throws invalid_argument exception if item does not exist within queue
*/
std::pair<T, unsigned int> search(T& item) {

    size_t i = 0;

    // loop over whole queue
    while (i < dataWithPriorityVec.size()) {

        // if first element of dataVec at i equals the parameterised item,
        // return the pair of the object and corresponding priority at the node
        if (dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).first == item) {
            return std::make_pair<T&, unsigned int&>(dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).first, dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).second);
        }

        i++;

    }

    // if item could not be found within queue, throw an exception
    throw std::invalid_argument("Item does not exist within priority queue.");

}

/**
* @brief Searches for an item in the PQ and returns a vector of all occurrences of the item
*         with their corresponding priorities.
*
* @warning If the item does not exist within the queue then this method will return an empty vector.
* @param item Object to search for in the priority queue
* @return A std::vector of std::pair instances containing the objects and corresponding priorities
*/
std::vector<std::pair<T, unsigned int>> searchAll(T& item) {

    size_t i = 0;

    // container to store occurrences of data pairs in the queue
    std::vector<std::pair<T, unsigned int>> occurrencesVec;

    // loop over whole queue
    while (i < dataWithPriorityVec.size()) {

        // if first element of dataVec at i equals the parameterised item,
        // push the pair containing the data and corresponding priority
        // to the occurrencesVec container
        if (dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).first == item) {
            occurrencesVec.push_back(std::make_pair<T&, unsigned int&>(dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).first, dataWithPriorityVec.at(i).second));
        }

        i++;

    }

    return occurrencesVec;

}
```

Notice that in the first method (search) I throw an exception if the item does not exist within the structure whereas in the second (searchAll) I simply let the method return an empty vector if the item does not exist. I am uncomfortable about this disconnect but I'd rather not go throwing exceptions around for the sake of it - is there a standard way of dealing with this or is it down to coding preferences?

I understand that exception throwing should generally only be done when a method cannot achieve what it was designed to do and the result cannot be ignored - however it seems that returning an empty vector in the searchAll case is not an erroneous thing to do.

Comment: The standard library uses iterators to containers as a method of dealing with this--if the returned iterator is equal to the end iterator of the searched range, then no value was found.

Comment: What's the problem with returning an empty vector? That's exactly what I would expect from a function with that name.

Comment: @BaummitAugen After considering it again, I think you're right - I was just initially concerned about having search throw an exception whilst searchAll wasn't, but I think the functionality is correct for my uses actually.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury *"having search throw an exception"* Well, whether or not *that* is a good idea or not might by debatable, but I guess one can look at that function as some `container::at`-style access. I would say that is fine if the search failing really is exceptional. Otherwise, just return an iterator to the element if found and an `end` iterator otherwise, as `std::find` does. Btw, the above might be pseudo code, but `std::find` could replace `search` altogether as it stands.